# unix utility that reads files into memory?

Tags: ruby, linux, unix, shell, net-sftp

I am using Ruby's net-ssh library to remotely execute shell commands. I would like to read a few files into memory rather than simply transfer them via SCP/SFTP. Can can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use wc or ls to find the size, you can use cat to get the data out, then read the right number of bytes.